# C++ - Automatically moving a function from header to cpp file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, macros

I am using C++ in Visual Studio 2010.  Has anyone found a macro or utility to move a member function defined in a header file into the implementation file?

For example,

```
virtual void SetName(const std::wstring& name) { m_name = name; }
```

would be converted to

```
virtual void SetName(const std::wstring& name);
```

in the header
and

```
void ClassName::SetName(const std::wstring& name) 
{ 
    m_name = name; 
}
```

in the cpp file

Comment: I wouldn't mind having this myself... not aware of any existing tools that do it, though.

Comment: It would not be difficult to write such a tool yourself, and share it with us all. Possilby, an open source software?

Comment: I'm working on a macro.  I'll share it with you guys later.

Comment: For information (since you said windows), there is an unix tool for that : http://www.lazycplusplus.com/

Answer (score 8):

**[Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/)** - **Refactor (VA X)** - Move implementation to source file

Comment: I use it myself. I didn't know it can do that.